# Modify common file between recipes

Tags: yocto

I have a third party app which functionality can be extended by loading shared object files during runtime.

The libraries that should be loaded are defined via a text file, where you put in the path of that object file, one line for one library. The order of loading the libraries doesn't matter.

I can develop as many libraries as I like, each with its own recipe. The problem is now, how can I edit that file which defines which libraries to load?

E.g. how can I create a file that is shared between an unknown amount of recipes and will be placed on the rootfile in the end?

Comment: Why do they need to share the file? In the end, it's your third party app that is loading them, so it's the only piece of SW that needs to know about which libs to load right?

Comment: Yeah, seems like a reasonable way too. Do you have a solution how I could let the app know of all libraries?

Comment: You anyway need a way to select all libraries to install right?
You could do this by having a `PACKAGECONFIG` option in your 3rd party app that selects all libraries one by one. Then in one custom task, you read `PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS` and put them in a file that you install in the package of your 3rd party app. The issue is that `PACKAGECONFIG` can only be changed "dynamically" in conf (distro, machine, layer, local) files. So if you need a programmable switch, it might not suit your need. See: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS

Comment: Another possibility is to select your library packages to install in an image recipe. Then in a `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` in your image recipe, you find all your libraries in the rootfs and create the file in the rootfs directly. See: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND

Comment: The postprocess command seems promissing. I could put them all into one folder and the put every library into that file. Thanks for the tip!